# Print Problems In PHP

Tags: php, html, printing

When I run this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <?php
                if(isset($_COOKIE["username"])){

                    print "Hello, ";
                }
                elseif(isset($_SESSION["userId"])){

                    print "Hello, ";
                }
                else{
                    print "<p><a href='logInForm.php'>Log In</a></p>";
                }
            ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the output:

```
-Log In

";}?>
```

I don't have any idea why it is printing out of the parenthesis. Any help?

Comment: your server is broken and is sending out the php source. do a "view source" to confirm.

Comment: No but it is showing that it stops compiling it as PHP after the first <p> tag

Comment: crazy shot in the dark. if that file isn't `.php`, then there you go.

Comment: Nope I already check that but thanks. Sometimes it's the simple things.

Comment: last ditch effort and is often accessed this way. Are you accessing it on your own machine as `http://localhost/file.php` or as `file:///file.php` in your browser? if the latter, then again...there you go.

Comment: I'm using `http://localhost/file.php`

Comment: Stupid question from me here ... there's not a sneaky hidden `?` typo-d into that closing `p` tag is there? That would make the end of that line something like `</p ?>";}?>`

Comment: No but I see what you mean.

Comment: php doesn't care about `<p>` tags. it doesn't know what html is. php only cares about `<?php` and `?>` (and maybe `<?` if you have short-tags enabled).

Comment: I know that's why it confuses me so much. When I view source code it shows me that the php stops getting compiled as php after the <p> tag.

Answer (score 0):

This should work better

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some login thing</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>
    <p>
    <?php
        if(isset($_COOKIE["username"])){

        echo "Hello ".$_COOKIE["username"].", ";
        }
        elseif(isset($_SESSION["userId"])){

        echo "Hello user #".$_SESSION["userId"].", ";
        }
        else{
        echo "<a href=\"logInForm.php\">Log In</a>";
        }
    ?>
    </p>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd stick with one style of quotes to denote strings and echoing out a `\"` means print a `"`. If it wasn't escaped then an error occurs. Also, I changed the Hello messages to include the username or user ID.

I also moved the `<p>` tags outside of the PHP code so that all text will be treated as a paragraph instead of only the login link.

`Print` may work but I find `echo` works better for me and its one less character to type.